# Using Boostrap 4 SCSS as a Mixin Library

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4

This is how I learned to use bootstrap: http://transmission.vehikl.com/using-bootstrap-as-a-semantic-mixin-library/ but with v4 they dropped LESS. How can I achieve something like that with SCSS? Like it or not... it's really usefull and I can't find a way to do the import right.

Answer (score 0):

i know what you mean i used the mixin from less all the time. They are still there you just have to import them.

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@include gradient-bg(#f45f12);
/* my-file.scss */
```

if you got here and are using angular cli to build your project there is a good tutorial on [how to use scss on angular cli](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli)

hope this helps